# show all order count of a customer in order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I want to show all the record of the customer who have multiple order in one row as per customer entered email in my order grid, any who have tried this earlier please suggest me the way.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter by email?

Comment: yes and that be filterable with given date in grid filter

Comment: You need to add new column in `sales_flat_order_grid` with the `customer_email` column from `sales_flat_order` and add index on it. Then you can simply overwrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` and render the new column.

Answer (score 0):

ok it was simple I just need to join table the code for creating the collection in grid i have given below

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'customer_email', 'orders_count' => 'COUNT(sales_flat_order.entity_id)'))->group('sales_flat_order.customer_email');
```